# MySQL UTF8 Problem

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have a strange UTF8 encoding problem, which I don't understand. 
If a friend of mine fills out a form on my webpage, then all german "umlauts" (ä,ü,ö) are displayed in strange chars in my database. When I do the same, they are displayed normally, how it should be. Everything is set to utf8_general_ci, so it should work. But it doesn't, when my friend fills out the form.

Has anyone a suggestion for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your web service that stores the character data in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Even though all tables are UTF-8, the database connection might be using latin-1. What output do you get with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%character%';` in MySQL? Any signs of latin-1 there? If so, adjust your [charset settings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html) in the MySQL configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified the language you write your app in, and it seems to be connection-based problem. You must manually set connection encoding, f.g. in JDBC, by appending on the end of connection string *"?characterEncoding=utf8"*

Answer (score 0):

Run `SET NAMES utf8` on mysql right after connection